# set access token and refresh token in the header before redirect in sinatra app

Tags: ruby, authentication, sinatra, access-token

I have a ruby sinatra app with a login endpoint. it will receive username and password params, as well as a redirect_url param, and after a successful authentication, it redirects to the redirect_url page. I assume the redirect will be a new request. The problem I have is, I am not able to set the access_token and refresh token in the headers of the new request.

Here is the endpoint:

```
post "/users/login" do
  param :email, String, required: true
  param :password, String, required: true
  param :redirect_url, String, required: true

  email = params[:email]
  password = params[:password]
  redirect_url = params[:redirect_url]

# Respond with the token and refresh and expiry time of the token
  access_token = 'SOME_A_T',
  refresh_token = 'SOME_R_T',
  token_expires_at = Time.current + 60.minute

# Here is where I try to set the access token in the header
 request['authorization'] = "Bearer #{access_token}"
 redirect redirect_url
end
```

When I test and inspect the response, it has a `location` item in the header which is set to the redirect_url param, but the access_token doesn't exist in the header. Also, I don't know what's the best way to include refresh token in the header.

Comment: This won't work as headers sent with a HTTP redirect won't be passed along to the new location (aside from cookies). You have to send the bearer token as a regular 200 response (e.g. as JSON or plain text). On the client side you then have to read the token from the response and make a new request which includes the corresponding authorization header (using JavaScript).